# Recursive definition of Minkowski ?(x) function

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

There is a fact that $?(\frac{a+b}{c+d}) = (?(\frac {a}{c}) + ?(\frac{b}{d})) / 2$ if a/c and b/d are adjanced elements of Farey sequence. How to prove it? I don't have any ideas at all.

Comment: What does $?x$ mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question_mark_function?wprov=sfla1